# Pointer in C# reset's after leaving a Class

Tags: c#, pointers

I have a class `Form1` and a class `MyList`. I want to create a program that puts character into List and has a *pointer* that shows on next one.
My problem is that everytime when I call class `MyList`, the *pointer* resets.

How can I solve the problem.
It is a school project an it must be done on this way, with *pointers*.

Thanks for all answers!

```
namespace Data {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        char character = "a"
        int index = 0;
        MyList a = new MyList();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //On click get new index and character and put in a List.
        {
           a.PutIn(index, character);
        }   
    } 
}
```

MyList class:

```
namespace Data
{
    public unsafe struct list
    {
        public char x;
        public list* next;
    }
    public unsafe partial class MyList
    {
        list* first = null;
        list* last = null;
        int index;
        public unsafe MyList() { Initialize(); }

        public unsafe void Initialize() 
        {
            first = null;
            last = null;
            index = -1;
        }
        ~MyList()
        { 
            do{
                Emty(0);
            }while (!IsEmpty());
        }
        public unsafe void PutIn(int place, char character) 
        { 
        if (((index+1)<place)||(place<0))
           MessageBox.Show("Index is too high!");
        else
        {
            if (IsEmpty()) 
            {
                list temp = new list();
                list* temp_pointer = &temp;
                temp_pointer->next = null;
                temp_pointer->x = character;
                first = temp_pointer;
                last = temp_pointer;
                temp_pointer = null;
                index++;
            }
            else if (place == (index + 1)) 
            {
                list temp = new list();
                list* temp_pointer = &temp;
                temp_pointer->next = null;
                temp_pointer->x = character;
                last->next = temp_pointer;
                last = temp_pointer;
                temp_pointer = null;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So your teacher insists that you use C# (and not e.g. C or C++) and also insists that you build a *pointer* based linked list (instead of a reference based linked list)? That sounds like a *very* dumb assignment.

Comment: A pointer to a local variable is only valid until that local variable goes out of scope. So your code is totally broken. Similarly a pointer obtained using the `fixed` statement is only valid until the end of that `fixed` statement. If you need long lived pointers, you need pin them or use an unmanaged allocation.

Comment: Pinning is done using `GCHandle.Alloc(o, GCHandleType.Pinned)`

Comment: I agree with @CodesInChaos, this 'simple' assignment is using very advanced (and unsafe as your code keeps saying) c# capabilities.  Far beyond any school homework assignment.  Is it possible your 'teacher' got confused with the difference between pointers and references, and your homework was to actually use references?

Comment: Make sure you don't use 'new' everytime you call the class.  New will call the constructor which will reset the value.  One you create the class the 1st time call by the same instance of the class.

Comment: @Neil Well, perfectly fine for a C or C++ homework. It just doesn't make much sense in C# :D

Comment: @jdweng The attempt here is to create a new list *item*, not the whole list - it's a linked list implementation. The problem is that `new list()` will allocate on the stack (unlike C's `new`), so the pointer simply isn't valid as soon as you leave the method scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will see if will do that in c++ or some other way. Now i have a confirmation of my doubts.

Comment: If you need the point left at same location than make it static.

Comment: Is this a class/lecture/assignment that has focus on pointers or is your lecturer confused in that you should use pointers in C#? Yes, you *can* use pointers but you almost never do.

Comment: You're getting us wrong. It's perfectly possible to do this in C# if you so desire, and C# is well equipped for handling this. You will still learn about  Just don't try to write C++ code in C# and expect it to work - C# is too different for that to work. For example, you need to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` to allocate a new unmanaged object on the heap.

Comment: Your teacher needs to go back to school.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are allocating `list` as a local and it is not guaranteed to last any longer than the scope in which it is defined (in fact, the guarantee only makes sense for managed code anyway - the runtime compiler can get rid of it long before the scope ends if it wants to).

You really want to allocate the object somewhere where it will last a bit longer. The simplest approach is to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` to allocate a bit of memory on the unmanaged heap. You free that memory using `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`. This is roughly equivalent to using `new` and `delete` in C.

I started with your code sample, but had to change a few things to avoid going mad. This doesn't mean that the final sample is 100% correct or a good way of implementing this, I was still only changing a few things in your code to make it work. In a real implementation, I'd make the whole thing a bit differently - if you're interested in some good practices for working with C# and pointers in C# (or in general), you might want to post your full, working code to Code Review - you'll get a lot of good feedback there.

Sample code, including adding and removing items from the list:

```
void Main()
{
  var list = new MyList();
  list.InsertAt(0, 'A');
  list.InsertAt(1, 'B');
  list.InsertAt(2, 'C');
  list.InsertAt(1, 'X');

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.Select(i => i.ToString())));

  list.RemoveAt(1);

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.Select(i => i.ToString())));
}

public unsafe struct list
{
    public char x;
    public list* next;
}

public unsafe class MyList : IEnumerable<char>
{
  list* first;
  list* last;
  int count;

  public int Count { get { return count; } }
  public bool IsEmpty() { return count == 0; }

  private void Remove(list* previous, list* current)
  {
    if (first == current) first = current->next;
    if (last == current) last = previous;
    if (previous != null) previous->next = current->next;

    Console.WriteLine
      (
        "Removing {0}, first {1}, last {2}, count {3}", 
        current->x, 
        first == null ? '-' : first->x, 
        last == null ? '-' : last->x,
        count
      );

    count--;
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(new IntPtr(current));
  }

  public void RemoveAt(int index)
  {
    if (count < index || index < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index is out of range!");

    var current = first;

    if (index == 0)
    {
      Remove(null, current);

      return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
    {
      current = current->next;
    }

    Remove(current, current->next);
  }

  ~MyList()
  { 
      do
      {
        RemoveAt(0);
      }
      while (!IsEmpty());
  }

  private list* InsertAfter(list* previousItem, char character)
  {   
    var newItem = (list*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(list));
    newItem->next = previousItem == null ? null : previousItem->next;
    newItem->x = character;

    if (previousItem == last) last = newItem;
    if (previousItem != null) previousItem->next = newItem;

    count++;

    Console.WriteLine
      (
        "Added {0} after {1}, first {2}, last {3}, count {4}",
        character,
        previousItem == null ? '-' : previousItem->x,
        first == null ? '-' : first->x,
        last == null ? '-' : last->x,
        count
      );

    return newItem;
  }

  public void InsertAt(int index, char character) 
  { 
    if (count < index || index < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index is out of range!");

    if (index == 0)
    {
      var newItem = InsertAfter(null, character);
      if (first != null) newItem->next = first;
      first = newItem;
    }
    else if (index == 1) 
    {
      InsertAfter(first, character);
    }
    else if (index == count) 
    {
      InsertAfter(last, character);
    }
    else
    {
      var current = first;
      for (var i = 0; i < index - 2; i++)
      {
        current = current->next;
      }

      InsertAfter(current, character);
    }
  }

  private class MyListEnumerator : IEnumerator<char>
  {
    private MyList list;
    private list* current;

    public MyListEnumerator(MyList list)
    {
      this.list = list;
      this.current = null;
    }

    public void Reset() { current = null; }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      if (current == null) current = list.first;
      else current = current->next;

      return current != null;
    }

    public char Current
    {
      get
      {
        if (current == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return current->x;
      }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return (object)Current; } }

    public void Dispose() {}
  }

  public IEnumerator<char> GetEnumerator() { return new MyListEnumerator(this); }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}
```